# Android App staged launch + new country

Tags: android, launch

we´re thinking about to try staged launch in Google Play for the new update of our app.
We want to distribute it to 20% of our existing user base first and monitor.
My question is basically which version will be offered in the app store then? Still the old one, or already the new update and the percentage only refers to distribution of existing apps.
Especially important for us as we want to launch a new country at the same time, but want to make our app availabe there.

Anyone deeper experience with this functionality?
Thanks for your help in advance,

Steffen